# SQL. Запрос к таблице

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Есть таблица:

| id | fdate | s_1 | s_2 | s_3 | s_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 | Да |  |  |  |
| 2 | 2023-01-01 |  | Нет |  |  |
| 3 | 2023-01-01 |  |  | Да |  |
| 4 | 2023-01-01 |  |  |  | Да |
| 5 | 2023-01-01 | Да |  |  |  |
| 6 | 2023-01-01 |  | Да |  |  |
| 7 | 2023-01-01 |  |  | Нет |  |
| 8 | 2023-01-01 |  |  |  | Да |
| 9 | 2023-01-02 | Да |  |  |  |
| 10 | 2023-01-02 |  | Нет |  |  |
| 11 | 2023-01-02 |  |  | Нет |  |
| 12 | 2023-01-02 |  |  |  | Да |

Нужно в запросе вывести:

| id | fdate | s_1 | s_2 | s_3 | s_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 | Да | Нет | Да | Да |
| 5 | 2023-01-01 | Да | Да | Нет | Да |
| 9 | 2023-01-02 | Да | Нет | Нет | Да |

Как такое можно реализовать с помощью хранимой процедуры (функции)?

Comment: принцип группировки то какой? почему вы берете 1-2-3-4, а 1-6-3-4  например? Их всегда 3 последовательных, или что? группируйте по дате тогда, и целому от деления id на 4. берите min(id), max(s_x)

Comment: @teran На входе может быть любое количество колонок s_%, которое на момент формирования запроса неизвестно. По сути если откинуть поля id и fdate, то всегда получается диагональная матрица. В написании функций не силен. Но поставлена задача и надо ее решить.

Comment: В предыдущем вашем вопросе уже дали ответы. Они решают задачу? Если да, просто оформите их в виде хранимки.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Не совсем решает.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Получается то же самое, что и в исходной таблице
только с выборкой  по id [1, 5, 9, ...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем понятен принцип группировки. Предположим:
Если таблица - диагональная матрица, то после ответа на последний вопрос (s_4 - не пусто), начинается новая группа.
Посмотрите пример:

```
-- test data
create table test (id int,fdate date,s_1 varchar(10),s_2 varchar(10)
        ,s_3 varchar(10),s_4 varchar(10));
insert into test values
 ( 1,'2023-01-01','Да' ,null,null,null)         
,( 2,'2023-01-01',null,'Нет',null,null)
,( 3,'2023-01-01',null,null,'Да',null)
,( 4,'2023-01-01',null,null,null,'Да')
,( 5,'2023-01-01','Да',null,null,null)          
,( 6,'2023-01-01',null,'Да',null,null)
,( 7,'2023-01-01',null,null,'Нет',null) 
,( 8,'2023-01-01',null,null,null,'Да')
,( 9,'2023-01-02','Да',null,null,null)          
,(10,'2023-01-02',null,'Нет',null,null)     
,(11,'2023-01-02',null,null,'Нет',null) 
,(12,'2023-01-02',null,null,null,'Да')
 -- еще дополнительно
,(21,'2023-01-02','Да',null,null,null)          
,(22,'2023-02-02',null,null,null,'Да')

;
--query
select grn,min(id)id,min(fdate)
  ,max(s_1) s_1,max(s_2) s_2,max(s_3) s_3,max(s_4) s_4
  from(
    select * 
      ,sum(cnt)over(order by id) grn
    from(
      select *
       ,case when lag(s_4,1,s_1)over(order by id) is not null then 1 else 0 end cnt
      from test
      )t1
  )t2
group by grn
```

Результат такой

| grn | id | mindate | s_1 | s_2 | s_3 | s_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2023-01-01 | Да | Нет | Да | Да |
| 2 | 5 | 2023-01-01 | Да | Да | Нет | Да |
| 3 | 9 | 2023-01-02 | Да | Нет | Нет | Да |
| 4 | 21 | 2023-01-02 | Да | null | null | Да |

Колонки Id и fdate не имеют значения.

Comment: Они нужны для джойна с другой таблицей

Comment: Они не принципиальны для группировки. Для дальнейших выборок и пр. - сохраняйте, как вам надо.